# Different row output based on specific query value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using the following query and I would like to change div colors based on the value of one of my queried items. In the code below I am trying to check the value of mgap_accept. if the value is 1 then the results will be output in a different div then if the value is not 1.

I did it with an IF?ELSE, bt Im unsure if there is a better way. here is my code:

```
$result_cat = "SELECT mgap_accept,mgap_ska_id FROM mgap_orders WHERE mgap_ska_id = '$id'";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($result_cat); 
$stmt->execute();
while($row_cat = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{

$id1=$row_cat['mgap_ska_id'];
$accept=$row_cat['mgap_accept'];
$growth=($total + $recovery);
if($accept == '1'){
?>
<div class="show">
<span class="namecustcoltype"><?php echo $id1;  ?></span>
<span class="namecusttype"><?php echo $accept;  ?></span>
<span class="growthcust">$<?php echo number_format($growth);  ?></span>
</div>
<?php
}else{
?>
<div class="showop">
<span class="namecustcoltype"><?php echo $id1;  ?></span>
<span class="namecusttype"><?php echo $accept;  ?></span>
<span class="growthcust">$<?php echo number_format($growth);  ?></span>
</div>
<?php 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <div class="<?php echo ($accept == '1')?'show':'showop';?>">
```

"?:" - [ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Comment: thanks for the help; do I need to remove the if/else?

Comment: Yes. Leave only one block.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result_cat = "SELECT mgap_accept,mgap_ska_id FROM mgap_orders WHERE mgap_ska_id = '$id'";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($result_cat); 
$stmt->execute();
while($row_cat = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{

$id1=$row_cat['mgap_ska_id'];
$accept=$row_cat['mgap_accept'];
$growth=($total + $recovery);
$class = $accept == '1' ? "show" : "showop";
?>
<div class="<?=$class?>">
<span class="namecustcoltype"><?php echo $id1;  ?></span>
<span class="namecusttype"><?php echo $accept;  ?></span>
<span class="growthcust">$<?php echo number_format($growth);  ?></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will always need an `if else` statement.

But you can shorten your code:

```
$accept == '1'? $class="show" : $class="showop;
?>
<div class="<?php echo $class; ?>">
<span class="namecustcoltype"><?php echo $id1;  ?></span>
<span class="namecusttype"><?php echo $accept;  ?></span>
<span class="growthcust">$<?php echo number_format($growth);  ?></span>
</div>
```